# Problems when exporting a project

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, export

I have a level editor thingy, and when i run it in eclipse everything is working as it should and everything shows up. I tried to export it both as a runnable jar and just a jar. None of them seemed to work. The problem is that the images, buttons and menus don't show up when i run the jar. I think it has something to do with resources.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I am using this function when loading images:

```
public static BufferedImage loadTileImg(String fn) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    File file = new File(fn);
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return img;
}
```

and i am using a URL to load icons.

Comment: Can you post the code used for loading the resources ?

Comment: @Alex I think code is not required here.Its related to exporting project as jar

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK IMO either the resources are not located like they should in the final JAR or the code may not be bulletproofed for locating the resources.

Answer (score 0):

How are you managing the resources?

Take care about full paths when you are showing it and exporting the resources properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [fat jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fjep/). Check the existence of the images and icon files in the exported jar.

Check the relative paths used for resources inside your code.